# How do I Taylor expand this equation in epsilon?

Tags: taylor-expansion

Suppose $v = 1 - \epsilon$ , $\epsilon \ll 1$. I'm having trouble understanding how to expand $$ t'= \frac{t}{\sqrt{1-v^2}}. $$

I tried writing $$ t' = \frac{t}{\sqrt{1-(1-\epsilon)^2}}, $$ but then the first term goes to infinity.

Comment: Expand around $\epsilon = 0$? You *can't*.

Comment: More explicitly: the function $\epsilon\longmapsto\frac{t}{\sqrt{1-(1-\epsilon)^2}}$ is *discontinuous* at $\epsilon = 0$. Your Taylor expansion is *impossible*.

Comment: But a Puiseux series works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the expansion around $\nu = 1$ of $\frac{t}{\sqrt{1-\nu^2}}$

**Edit**

Use Martin's comment as a starting point.

Since you're regarding ad the "new" function in terms of $\epsilon$, you can easily expand your function in power of $\epsilon$ around $0$:

$$\frac{t}{\sqrt{1 - (1-\epsilon)^2}} \approx \frac{t}{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{\epsilon }}+\frac{t \sqrt{\epsilon }}{4 \sqrt{2}}+\frac{3 t \epsilon ^{3/2}}{32 \sqrt{2}}+\frac{5 t \epsilon ^{5/2}}{128 \sqrt{2}}+\frac{35 t \epsilon ^{7/2}}{2048 \sqrt{2}}+O\left(\epsilon ^{9/2}\right)$$

Notice that as $\epsilon \to 0$ your series goes like

$$\frac{t}{\sqrt{1 - (1-\epsilon)^2}} \sim \frac{t}{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{\epsilon }}$$

Calculations are easy, you can do it.

Comment: The problem: Isn't a *Taylor* expansion.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla And since you insist, I rewrite this: NOBODY said it is a Taylor series, period.

Comment: Again my point: The Taylor expansion *required by the OP* is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Writing $c$ for $\epsilon$ 
because lazy,

$\begin{array}\\
t' 
&= \dfrac{t}{\sqrt{1-(1-c)^2}}\\
&= \dfrac{t}{\sqrt{1-(1-2c+c^2)}}\\
&= \dfrac{t}{\sqrt{2c-c^2}}\\
&= \dfrac{t}{\sqrt{2c}\sqrt{1-c/2}}\\
&= \dfrac{t}{\sqrt{2c}}(1-c/2)^{-1/2}\\
&= \dfrac{t}{\sqrt{2c}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\binom{-1/2}{n}(c/2)^n\\
\end{array}
$

To make it look nicer, do

$\begin{array}\\
\binom{-1/2}{n}
&=\dfrac{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (-\frac12-k)}{n!}\\
&=\dfrac{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (-1-2k)}{2^nn!}\\
&=(-1)^n\dfrac{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (2k+1)}{2^nn!}\\
&=(-1)^{n}\dfrac{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (2k+1)(2k+2)}{2^nn!\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(2k+2)}\\
&=(-1)^{n}\dfrac{(2n)!}{4^nn!^2}\\
&=(-1)^{n}\dfrac{\binom{2n}{n}}{4^n}\\
\end{array}
$

so
$t'
=\dfrac{t}{\sqrt{2c}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{-1/2}{n}(c/2)^n
=\dfrac{t}{\sqrt{2c}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{2n}{n}\dfrac{c^n}{8^n}
$

Comment: Same objection that in the other answer: isn't a Taylor expansion and the Taylor expansion *required by the OP* is impossible.

Comment: Since what is requested is impossible, the next best thing is a Puiseux series which Von Neumann and I provided.